# Add moderator nomination/primary/election history to user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, election, nominations, moderator-primaries

I think it would be helpful to have links on a user's profile to their moderator nomination/primary/election history.

Currently, you can see it in the activity tab of the user's profile (even though [the description is ambiguous at best](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111663/have-better-description-of-moderator-election-nomination-on-activity-tab), making it more difficult), but you'd have to dig pretty deep to get previous year's activity in the moderator elections.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just go to the previous election's page and look at everything there? It doesn't require deep digging, although I'm not entirely sure what kind of activity you want to see.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of an election system that prominently shows the candidate's past election history. Why would you want that?

Comment: Direct links to the posts the user made are provided on the user page.  It's also in the activity page.  I don't see why a nomination entry (which is a post, essentially) wouldn't merit placement among other, similar items that are prominently placed on the page.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Also, election urls are now of the format `/election/1` and `/election/2` with `/election` taking you to the most recent election.  However, there's no direct way of getting to those url structures (unless you want to start at 1 and tick up, that's like asking someone to go through questions like that, tedious, at best).

Comment: @casperOne They're linked from http://elections.stackexchange.com/ and also from the `/about` page (each "elected in X" link under a moderator's name takes you to the relevant election page).

Comment: @AnnaLear: elections.stackexchange.com only gets you the current election, unless I'm missing something?  History is part of the request.  It kind of shows that this history related to the user is scattered in many places, when there should be a singular place to get that info (and IMO, that place is the user profile page).

Comment: @casperOne Hrm. I thought it listed all past elections, but it looks like it only shows the last one. My bad.