# Have better description of moderator election nomination on activity tab

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, election

Currently, looking at another user's activity tab, one wouldn't know that they had submitted a nomination for the moderator election.

The activity type is "wiki", as shown here:

[image: Activity tab for casperOne on November 10th, 2011]

When expanded, they see the details of the nomination:

[image: Expanded activity tab for casperOne on Noveber 10th, 2011]

I think that "wiki" should have a better description of the action performed.  I'm assuming it's not *too* hard to do, given that the entry must be tied to the fact it is part of the moderator election *somewhere*.

Comment: Strange. In inbox notifications it shows up as "*username*'s Nomination"; I assumed that was the post title